# Hows does sklearn PCA works on dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, pca

I have the following dataframe:

```
      A       B      C      D
0     4       1      1     78
1    82       2     58     41
2    53       3     31     76
3     1      45      4     12
5     5       2      4     87
6     1      74      6     11
7     1       1      6     47
8     1       1      6      8
```

to which I am trying to apply :

```
 sklearn.decomposition.PCA
```

in order to reduce the number of columns from 4 to 2
And I can't understand which dimension: **rows** or **columns** does PCA takes as the number of vectors.

Because if I do the following:

```
    df=
          A       B      C      D
    0     4       1      1     78

pca=PCA(n_components=3)
pca.fit(df.T)
```

it will return the following error:

> ValueError: n_components=3 must be between 0 and n_features=1 with
>   svd_solver='full'

Even If I have only 1 data in each vector I should still be able to reduce the number of vectors from 4 to 3.

Comment: so if I understand correctly you want to reduce `ABCD` down to `AB`, using PCA?

Comment: Yes. Or in the second example `ABCD` to `ABC`

Comment: PCA transforms the data into new dimensions. Its not technically right to say that PCA reduced `ABCD` to `ABC`. It reduces `ABCD` to some new `XYZ`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it using `PCA`, note I am also standardizing the values.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

vals = df.ix[:, :4].values

vals_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(vals)

sklearn_pca = PCA(n_components = 'however many you want')

vals_pca = sklearn_pca.fit_transform(vals_std)
```

Then based on however many dimensions you settled on you can add it back to your data frame.

Comment: This does not work if `df` only have 1 line of data which is my case.

Comment: it worked for me, using the sample data frame you presented

Comment: But if you do so you end up with 1 PC and I want 3 PCs I have 4 columns.

Comment: Arty, PCA won't work for a dataset with just one row. The idea of PCA is reducing the number of features in a dataset so it's based on calculating the "variance" of the dataset and finding the orthogonal that best captures all the variance of the data. Hence, calculating the variance for just 1 observation is technically impossible.

Comment: was just about to say this ^^ @Arty

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense indeed. So whatever the number of PCs we want the minimum of rows should be 2 ?

Comment: @Arty Yes, at least 2 rows should be present.

Comment: but what if you wish to use fit and then later use transform over another df, how do you preserve the order of data features?  if i am not mistaken, pandas does not guaranty column order in memory, unlike np array